# Unable to locate c3p0 logging messages

Tags: java, logging, c3p0, java.util.logging

Up until recently, we created a new database connection for every query. Each query is setup using connection.prepareStatement(query) and we were able to log these queries to our logger (java.util.logging) with preparedStatement.toString(). This was using the postgresql JDBC driver.

Now we've switched to using c3p0 to manage connection pools and unfortunately preparedStatement.toString() no longer returns the prepared query statement.

I have [read](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#configuring_logging) that c3p0 logging can be directed to the standard logging facility but unfortunately I have been unable to find where these messages are going. Where can I find these messages? Glassfish 3's console in NetBeans states that debugging is enabled.

```
INFO: Initializing c3p0-0.9.1.2 [built 21-May-2007 15:04:56; debug? true; trace: 10]
```

Comment: Okay, to clarify something about the question - Mark is looking to find where these logs are going, which is pretty straightforward. But he is assuming c3p0 is logging the actual query strings, which may not actually be the case. This is the part I'm interested in (and the point of the bounty): is it possible to log the actual queries themselves from c3p0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logging seems to be on like the log says (debug?true), but if you read the [box](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#log_properties_box) on the link you had on your post you will find the setup options that should be checked for finding the right file.

If you end up logging to the so called last resort option, it should log to `System.Err` and this may cause the problem: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384042/glassfish-v3-logging) tells that System.Err is not by default always visible in **any** log file!

So keep trying the other options on the previously mentioned box or use the fix on the answer section of the post I linked :)

Comment: see my comment in case you want to add to your answer

Comment: @Mark : Do you have problem on getting any log through c3p0 or just not seeing it after toString() method? If the case is the first one, please read my answer otherwise, I cannot help, sorry.

Comment: @mico: Thanks for your feedback. I found the logs that c3p0 generates and I was able to tweak the configuration settings. However, I was under the assumption that c3p0 would log the actual queries it was running. From what I can tell, even with the log level set to ALL, it is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, if c3p0's logging is what you are really looking for?

I would recommend using [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/), which can log any JDBC queries (with parameters), and even provide you with a stack trace pointing to your JDBC/Hibernate/... statement, even if you're using a connection pool (use the option `-Dlog4jdbc.debug.stack.prefix=com.mycompany.myapp`). It can also display timing information, and a lot more.

Comment: Chris: nice, I search a library like that, and I found in your comment.  Thanks!

Comment: @Chris Lercher - thanks, this is the kind of solution I was looking for. Besides general startup/shutdown items, c3p0 seems to only log unhelpful stuff like this: `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement@481e5f`