# Where do I find the logs of System.out.println()?

Tags: java, logging, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans and I've checked the Server.log and all 3 output tabs in Netbeans for  Glassfish, Java DB Database and my app's output.  Where should I be seeing the output of `System.out.println()` ?  I'm trying to connect to a MySQL server and I need to see if it worked or not :)

Comment: Good question.  Use the logging API instead of `println()` to record output (is the best overall solution).  Of course, during development use a debugger.  ;)

Comment: Can you provide me a little more direction?  Is there one you'd recommend?

Comment: *"Is there one you'd recommend?"*  I use the J2SE inbuilt logging API for convenience.  Of the people who actually deal with logging APIs for their trade, *none* would recommend it.  So no, I cannot recommend one.  Sorry.

Comment: I'm not at my work pc so i can't check, but is the "Server.log" your checking the one in the glassfish->domains->[your domain]->[log folder]->[server.log]? I know that's where it outputs to on my setup.

Comment: @Shredder - I don't have anything within domains.  Should I set something up?  I just downloaded Netbeans and the SDK and started programming.  I just right click on my app and select "Run".  I pretty much have all default settings.

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384042/glassfish-v3-logging  I think you have to enable the log for your class and set the log level to INFO. Then check the server logs.

Comment: @Ben Well you said you're using glassfish, so I assume you developing a web app using a glassfish server. In order to run you're web app, you need to have a domain set up, yea? How are you running it?

Comment: @Shredder - Within Netbeans I'm right clicking on my app and selected "Run"

Comment: @Ben Are you running it using a glassfish server or is it a java console application? Need more detail :)

Comment: It's definitely a Glassfish server but there's nothing in the `domains` folder

Comment: When I launch from Netbeans there's a glassfish tab that shows a bunch of stuff

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out that I need to run the app in debug mode to see the output of `System.out.println()` in the glassfish console

Comment: Glad you figured this out. As soon as you are able, please be sure and mark your answer as accepted so others will know that there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

check in build\testuserdir\var\log\messages.log

for more info checkout the following link
http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansDeveloperFAQ#Output_Window

Comment: These logs are for a NetBeans Platform application and not for Glassfish.