# Glassfish - disable logging to server.log

Tags: logging, glassfish, log4j

I currently have a Glassfish server writing the logfile to the server.log. I read the logfile with tail -f server.log via cygwin. My backend builds like 3 minutes and without logging to the file it builds in like half of the time, so I am kinda curious if I can optimize the logging by disabling the logfile and "listening" to the log from glassfish server without simultanously writing into the logfile.

I hope you understand what I mean and I appreciate your answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"without logging to the file it builds in like half of the time"*

Sounds like you already know how to disable logging to `server.log`?

A more or less informative description of logging levels can be found here:

[Configuring the Logging Service](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gklmn.html#scrolltoc)

You can change logging service configuration in property files (described in the given link) or from the admin console:

*Configuration --> server-config --> Logger Configuration*

The logger that is responsible for logging to the log file is called `javax.enterprise.system`. You can switch it to `OFF` and no messages will be logged to the log file.

See this [related answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2384854/620338).